# How to take/create a UI thread dump log for Eclipse RCP applications?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I need UI thread dump for Eclipse RCP application.
Could you please help on this.

Regards,
Selva

Comment: [Get current stack trace in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1069066/150166)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following wiki page has info on how to take thread dumps on different platforms.
http://wiki.eclipse.org/How_to_report_a_deadlock