# How to Have a trace of all executed functions

Tags: java, multithreading, printstacktrace

I have a thread with this run method:

```
  public void run(){    
    MAPTable t1 = new MAPTable();
    t1.init();
    while(true){
       try {       
           t1.refresh();
       } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       try {
           sleep(10000);
       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }            
    }        
  }
```

How can i have i trace of all the functions executed by this thread, NOTE that init() an refresh() methods can call many others functions based on many external conditions.

I have tried to make a **NullPointerException** or placed one of those lines of code [referenced here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069066/get-current-stack-trace-in-java)  in the middle of the run() method, but i have always just the last trace which is the run() method (the same line i have used to print the trace).

```
 Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()
```

or

```
 for (StackTraceElement ste : Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()) {
    System.out.println(ste + "\n");
 }
```

or

```
Thread.dumpStack()
```

PS: I'm not so familiar with the debugger  and i don't know if this can be done with it.

Comment: What is your actual end goal? Why do you want this trace of methods that have been called?

Comment: Well i want to have the list of all executed functions by the thread just to check ithat every things OK

Comment: Naive way would be to add logging in each possible called functions, showing the thread id - not sure there is a better way.

Comment: yea, this how i use to do, but it become so difficule to handel since i have so many functions and conditions.

Comment: @IMAnis_tn I'd say that what you're trying to do is an overkill. Your application will spend more time logging than actually executing useful code.

Comment: Not clear:  Do you want a "stack trace" -- the list of the currently called methods, or do you want a "call trace" -- a list of every method called?  For the former you use `getStackTrace` or one of the other equivalent interfaces.  But it needs to be called from within the innermost method you want traced.  For the latter you need to use the debugging facilities.

Comment: (Though there is also `Thread.getAllStackTraces`, which, if called from a separate thread, will take a "snapshot" of other threads.  Used multiple times you can create a sort of density graph of the methods being invoked, but you're nowhere near being guaranteed to catch every invoked method.)

Comment: It seems like i have to start learning about the debugger, because i want a list of all the method called. until that logging is solution.

Comment: There are generally "canned" trace tools that will capture the method calls and build histograms, etc.  Most IDEs have these built in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find some useful information in http://blog.zvikico.com/2007/11/five-ways-for-t.html

I think some of the profilers may be able to provide options to generate all call traces.