# Is there any way i can get the list of called methods in a class in java?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get current stack trace in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069066/get-current-stack-trace-in-java)

Here is the thing, i want to get a list of all called methods in a java class. So far i've been using eclemma, but that just insn't enough. I also want the order in which the methods have been called.

Comment: You mean you need the call stack? If yes, use Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()

Answer (score 1):

You can log each method as it is called (with its arguments if you like). You can add a line to each method or use AOP to do this for you.