# Call stack from within Java method

Tags: java, reflection

Is it possible to add debugging code in a Java method which would determine which client method invoked that particular method using perhaps reflection, in very much the same way the call stack is available in any IDE?  Additionally, would it be possible to, in addition to the immediate caller, also produce a recursive call stack all the way down to the bottom level caller (e.g. a `main` method)?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069066/get-current-stack-trace-in-java