# Find which class created me

Tags: java, javabeans

I have a *generic* component (a simple `java` package). I convert it into a `jar` and give it to my clients.

My client can  use this jar for any of his applications. Will it be possible to identify who calls my component. That's in my component, will I be able to identify who created an instance of me?

Sorry, If I put this is a vague manner. Given a object I could find the className associated to it using(`getClass()`) . But I am not sure, if my requirement is ever possible.

Comment: You'd have to add some code to your class, e.g. a WhoCreatedme argument in the contructor...

Comment: What's the rationale behind the request? Could this possibly be an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: What would you do with this information?

Comment: What useful information could you derive from that? If I write a factory class for the stuff in your package, where would that leave the code knowing its creator?

Comment: My component is back-end component. Which is rapidly used by multiple clients. I would like to know, if we can audit the classes who instantiate me (At Java Layer) ! I have already created the audits in the Oracle layer, having implemented trace-ids from java to oracle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> That's in my component, will I be able to identify who created an instance of me?

Not in general, no. You could try obtaining a stack trace in the constructor, but that's not necessarily reliable or helpful.

If you want some sort of identifier, I suggest you have that as a constructor parameter (or factory method parameter). In other words, get the caller to identify themselves.

Comment: Why would getting a stack trace not be reliable?

Comment: @JoãoMendes: JIT inlining, for example. It's possible that it would *actually* be okay with whatever JIT the OP is using, but it doesn't feel like a good idea to me.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: JIT inlining has no effect on the stack trace. That’s why creating a stack trace will kill performance for sure. On the other hand, using Reflection has an impact on the stack trace.

Comment: @Holger: What guarantee is there that JIT inlining will never affect the stack trace on any JIT? It may not on Hotspot, but that's not the same as it being guaranteed for all JITs. If a JIT simply inlines the call in the most obvious way, an inlined call wouldn't be in the stack trace. (This can *definitely* occur in the Microsoft .NET CLR, for example - so unless there's meant to be some guarantee that it never happens in a JVM, it seems like a reasonable possibility.) And yes, reflection is another issue.

Comment: @Holger: In fact, `Throwable.getStackTrace` explicitly mentions this: "Some virtual machines may, under some circumstances, omit one or more stack frames from the stack trace"

Comment: It would still *probably* give the OP some inkling as to what he wants, namely, what projects and libraries are using his component. It's ok if a few stack traces are missing. It's extremely improbable for the *whole* stack to be inlined...

Comment: @JonSkeet The constructor is what we decided, but there has to be some standards in naming the possible values, and the processes are all set for it. I am just over greedy, if I could ever get the reference of the object who called me..!

Comment: @OracleUser there are no standards on this. The constructor way is the only possible reasonable way in Java.

Comment: @JoãoMendes: I don't think we really have enough information about *exactly* what the OP is doing to know that the crucial stack element would be there, to be honest. (And in some cases, even the stack trace wouldn't show anything useful - it only shows the class containing the code that's executing, not the actual type of the object calling it. Imagine an abstract superclass of `Application` which initialized the OP's library - you'd be interested in which subclass of `Application` was involved.)

Comment: @OracleUser: No, there's simply no facility to do that. (And there may not even *be* an object - think about a static method...)

Comment: @JonSkeet Understood and +1'd.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: There *are* certain stack frames which Oracle’s JVM hides. But that has nothing to do with JIT inlining. I would just prefer existing issues for explaining the unreliability of stack traces over theoretical ones. In the end, a JVM is not required to provide stack traces at all.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the stack trace of the current thread and parse the `StackTraceElement`s in the return, to find out which methods are calling yours.

You can check out [this question here in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069066/get-current-stack-trace-in-java).

Comment: Thanks Jaoo, the link your referred was highly valuable!

Comment: No problem, though I think you would do well to keep John Skeet's caveats in mind, from his comments on his answer.

Comment: Yup, but certain terms are bit too verbose to me! I am not a pro in Java, being a intensive SQL guy. But I would take this information to rest of my team mates. Appreciate all your efforts to me help me out.