# how to print stack trace to stdout in java for debug?

Tags: java, debugging, stack

I am new to java.

I want something like debug_print_backtrace in java.

I want to print current stack trace to stdout or to intellij idea log window for debug.

I used to use debug_print_backtrace in php to find some stack infos in runtime for debug.

Comment: I add this question for google searching in case I forgot how to do that, so when I search "java print stack trace", I can get what I want right away.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You only need one line.

```
new Exception().printStackTrace(System.out);
```

Thanks to [Get current stack trace in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069066/how-can-i-get-the-current-stack-trace#comment881658_1069066)

print stack trace to **stderr**:

```
new Exception().printStackTrace();
```

Comment: This goes to **stderr**. If you want to have it in **stdout**: `new Exception().printStackTrace(System.out);`

Comment: @ROMANIA_engineer I always think stderr and stdout is almost the same stuff. Thanks for your correct.

Answer (score -3):

Instead of printing in console, use this
javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,new Exception().printStackTrace());

Comment: I am using java in android. It just do not have the package of javax.swing .