# Get method name in Java Filter

Tags: java, servlets, filter

Got a Java Filter which is responsible to intercept some endpoints.

In doFilter method, as follows:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException;
```

How do I get the accessed method name?

For instance:

Given 2 Servlets followed by operation name:

```
LifeCycle
   create
   delete
SearchService
   findByName
   findById
```

When `LifeCycle.create` operation is called by a front end perspective, the filter intercepts it, however I couldn't know if the operation called was create or delete?

Are there some way to get the "create" operation name in Java Filter?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069066/get-current-stack-trace-in-java You can get stacktrace and analyze it

Comment: How are "create" and "delete" specified?

Comment: Just a thought: Cant we use some sort of logging mechanism?

Comment: could you give us some code on how doFilter is called? and from where, and the code from where it is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could get the operation name using:

```
((HttpServletRequest) request).getHeader("SOAPAction");
```

Answer (score 1):

Filters are invoked by the web container when a request is made to the server (servlet or jsp). They are not called by Servlets or jsps.

You can see Filter's life-cycle in the image below:

[image]

For more see [DOCUMENTATION](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b14017/filters.htm)

If you want to know which action is called from the front-end, then you can use a request parameter and then capture it from `ServletRequest`

Answer (score -1):

If you are searching for method names then you can try this piece of code:

```
    StackTraceElement[] st = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
    String methodName = st[2].getMethodName();
```

You can further modify the index of **st** to get the chained caller methods. It is just a simple array of stack trace objects containing class and method names. Good Luck!