# Method Call Stack in Java

Tags: java, methods, callstack

I want to create a method such that if i call that from any class it should get the class name from which the method has been called and can also print the class name.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069066/get-current-stack-trace-in-java

Comment: You could also use `Foo.class.getSimpleName()`

Comment: @AmirAfghani Thanks Amir Afgani that helped in solving my problem