# Use reflection to get the name of the method I'm in and the parameters passed to it?

Tags: java, reflection

**Duplicate:** In a method is there a way to query the name of the method I am in? - Duplicate of [Get the Current Stack Trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069066/get-current-stack-trace-in-java).

**Still valid:** And is there a way to get the parameters that were passed to the method?

Yes I can see all that in the method and use them literally, this is for a very weird idea where this might be useful. Also, I'm curious.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Get the Current Stack Trace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069066/get-current-stack-trace-in-java).  I don't think there's any way to reflectively access a method parameter.

Comment: @markspace - Thank you on the method name part.

Comment: Please clarify how you're intending to use this.

Comment: You might find [AOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) more useful here - see [AspectJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AspectJ) (or similar library) for more info.

Comment: The parameters are passed in local variables to your method. 1) they are named *local* variables for a reason 2) your method can modify these variables freely and the JVM is not holding a copy of all parameter variables just for the sake of some potential reflective access. So even with a debugger, there is no way to undo the manipulation of local variables to get their initial value.