# ChangeListener return unwanted array JavaFX

Tags: javafx, changelistener

*UPDATE: I've included the stack trace at the bottom.

I am trying to select items in a ChoiceBox using a Listener as found here: https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/3062859

However, I noticed that when I check the value of the new String (variable newChocie), I noticed that it prints out an array--corresponding with the number of times I made a selection--of the choice I made rather than simply the choice a single time. How do I correct the output so the function only returns a single instance of the user's choice? I have included my code below, and the contents of the list. For clarity, I've included an example of the output below. Thank you.

```
private void PopulateBox() {
    AliceBox.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList("Asset", "Liability", "Income", "Capital", "Expense"));
}

@FXML
private String SelectAccount() {
    AliceBox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((new ChangeListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> selected, String oldChoice, String newChoice) {
            System.out.println(newChoice);
        }
    })); 

    return AcctIDString;
}
```

Example of output:

```
Asset
Liability
Liability
Income
Income
Income
Capital
Capital
Capital
Capital
Expense
Expense
Expense
Expense
Expense
```

Stack trace:

```
    [java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1552), 
GLMaintAcct.GLMaintAcctController$1.changed(GLMaintAcctController.java:195), 
GLMaintAcct.GLMaintAcctController$1.changed(GLMaintAcctController.java:191), 
com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:361),
 com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81),
 javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper$ReadOnlyPropertyImpl.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:176),
 javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:142),
 javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:112), 
javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:146),     javafx.scene.control.SelectionModel.setSelectedItem(SelectionModel.java:102),     
javafx.scene.control.SingleSelectionModel.updateSelectedIndex(SingleSelectionModel.java:223), 
javafx.scene.control.SingleSelectionModel.select(SingleSelectionModel.java:149), 
javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox$ChoiceBoxSelectionModel.select(ChoiceBox.java:403), 
com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ChoiceBoxSkin.lambda$addPopupItem$282(ChoiceBoxSkin.java:254), 
com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ChoiceBoxSkin$$Lambda$261/232574417.handle(Unknown Source), 
com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86), 
com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238), 
com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191), 
com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58), 
com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114), 
com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74), 
com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49), 
javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198), 
javafx.scene.control.MenuItem.fire(MenuItem.java:462), 
com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.doSelect(ContextMenuContent.java:1405), 
com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.lambda$createChildren$341(ContextMenuContent.java:1358), 
com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer$$Lambda$232/766617116.handle(Unknown Source), 
com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218), 
com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80), 
com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238), 
com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191), 
com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59), 
com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58), 
com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114), 
com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56), 
com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114), 
com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56), 
com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114), 
com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56), 
com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114), 
com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74), 
com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54), 
javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198), 
javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3758), 
javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3486), 
javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762), 
javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2495), 
com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:350), 
com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:275), 
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method), 
com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$350(GlassViewEventHandler.java:385), 
com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$$Lambda$194/2091612855.get(Unknown Source), 
com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:404), 
com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:384), 
com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555),   
com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:927), 
com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method), 
com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(WinApplication.java:101), 
com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$36/1963387170.run(Unknown Source), java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)]
```

Comment: Looks like `SelectAccount()` is somehow being called every time the selection changes. Check the [stack trace](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1069074/303270) to find out how this function is being called.

Comment: It seems that you are not adding your listener in the FXML initialize method, as is done in the original sample you refer to.

Comment: Thank you jewelsea, that was the issue. I was calling the method every time the user selected the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are not adding your listener in the FXML initialize method, as is done in the original sample you refer to.  Instead you are calling a method to add a listener method every time the user selected an item in the ChoiceBox, which is incorrect.  Usually, you only need to add a listener once.