# How to let Mockito to doReturn when a method insides another method is called?

Tags: java, mockito

I'm doing the integration test using Mockito, and I'm testing the scenario when a timeout happened do some stuff.

```
public boolean checkTimeout(){
  if (createdAt.isBefore(dateTimeHelper.getNowUtc().minus(PROCESSING_TIMEOUT_MILLIS))) {
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

In the integration test, the `dateTimeHelper.getNowUtc()` method is called 10+ times. And I only want to be mock the time to be current time when `checkTimeout()` function is called, and mock the other time to be a stub time, say '2015-11-2 15:20:45'.

Can anyone tell me what's the right way to mock this?

a Brute force way is

```
doReturn(new DateTime(2015, 11, 2, 15, 30, 45)).doReturn(new DateTime(2015, 11, 2, 15, 30, 45)).......
        .doCallRealMethod().when(dateTimeHelperMock).getNowUtc();
```

Write `doReturn()` 10+ times, then `doCallRealMethod()` which is ugly. And if someone touch the code and add more `getNowUtc()`, the test will fail.

I'm new to Mockito, so want to know if there's a way to control the mock when `getNowUtc()` is called in `checkTimeout()`

Answer (score 1):

You Can probably do something like this:

```
    Mockito.when(obj.get()).thenAnswer(new Answer<String>() {
        public String answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable
        {
            StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
            for (StackTraceElement element : stackTrace)
            {
                //logic to iterate over stack trace elemtns and find your method.
            }
        }

    });
```

Comment: You can extend this approach adding a check on `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069066/get-current-stack-trace-in-java — that'll do exactly what OP asked for.

Comment: Thanks @alf, updating the answer. However, the test will be a tad slow.