# How to print out all the methods called during the execution of a Java program?

Tags: java, reverse-engineering, jdb

I have a Java program (jar file) and I wish to print out all the methods called during the execution of that program. So if `Class1.main()` calls `Class1.foo1()`, initiates Class2, calls `Class2.foo2()` and `Class2.foo3()`, then I want the output to be something similar to

```
called Class1.main
called Class1.foo1()
called Class2.<init>
called Class2.foo2()
called Class2.foo3()
```

Please note that I do not wish to see the active stack trace, e.g the method that's currently active and the methods which led to the call of that method, since it would not print out those methods that aren't related to the call of that method. I wish to see all the methods called during the execution of the program, in the order they're called in.

The answer may take advantage of any technique, though I expect it to use some sort of debugging program, like jdb. The reason for this is because I have already tried to use instrumentation with Javassist ([described in my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43027872/how-to-print-out-all-methods-called-during-runtime-in-java-using-instrumentation)) and ran into errors when trying it with more complex programs.

Comment: You shouldn't post duplicate questions, not even if one is "in any technique" and the other is "in a specific technique". It's still a duplicate.

Comment: @Nopslide instead of saying that it broke, might show the error that actually happens; may be it is un-related.

Comment: @Eugene error message:

`Exception in thread "main" Throwable$WrappedPrintStream
java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.lang.invoke.CallSite
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNetProperty(Unknown So
urce)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.lang.invoke.CallSite`

Comment: @Nopslide how about asking a new question?

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Java Flight Recorder](https://docs.oracle.com/javacomponents/jmc-5-4/jfr-runtime-guide/about.htm#JFRUH170). Not sure if you can get the output the way you like, but we used it for profiling and it showed which methods were called and which methods used the most CPU time. So there is method recording for sure.