# Accesing a reference variable from inside a method java

Tags: java, methods, constructor, reference

I am looking to add a function to a program where I use static variables to create a list of all the times the driver has used the constructor, using names. What I need to know is this, is there a way, in java, to access what the reference variable is (as a string) to add it to the list?
Pseudocode:

```
    public ClassName
    String static list = "";  
    Public ClassName (parameters){
      list += getReferenceVariable();
    }
```

The getReferenceVariable is what I'm asking if anyone knows a way to do that

Comment: Every object has a `toString()` method, and every raw type can be transformed to a String representation.  Is that what you mean?  Can you provide pseudo code of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Please provide *actual* code rather than pseudo-code. It's very hard to help when we can only see pseudo-code.

Comment: Yes, I have provided some pseudocode (for clarification)

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "the reference variable as a string" to start with - and using *real* code instead of pseudo-code would be much, much better. If you mean getting the `x` name out of `Foo x = new Foo()` from within the `Foo` constructor then no, you absolutely can't.

Comment: Ok thank you Jon, that's what I was trying to ask. I shall learn to format my questions better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to keep a list of all the times the constructor was called, and save the names of the currently-being-created variable? Because the "Reference variable" is none when you use the constructor, since you call the constructor with a `new MyClass()`, and not some `obj.MyClass()`.

If, however, you simply want to know who called you (As a stack trace is), you can simply, as written [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069066/get-current-stack-trace-in-java) (no pun intended), use
`Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()`, and then choose the desired stack frame (Probably 2, since The first element (index 0) in the array is the java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace method, the second (index 1) is the constructor, and 2 is where the constructor was called from), where you can get (for example) the name of the source file that this stack trace corresponds to. Documentation of [getFileName()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html#getFileName())

Since I haven't tried it on my end (not possible at the moment), I give you code to use with caution:

```
public class MyClass(){
    MyClass(){
        callerName = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getFileName();
        ... // anything here
    }
}
```