# Thread stack: JAVA

Tags: java, multithreading

Is there any way to view the thread stack values (i.e.) how to see that, what does the thread stack contains while execution?
I came to know that object values are stored in heap memory but the each thread creates its own reference to that and stores it inside the stack. 
I want to confirm that. Is there any other way to do that?

Comment: Not directly, no.   Apart from (I guess) using `gdb` debug a running JVM. See https://neugens.wordpress.com/2015/02/26/debugging-the-jdk-with-gdb/

Comment: You could use the debugger API (or just use the debugger) to see that information.

Comment: @PeterLawrey .... I avoided saying that because the Java debugger / API works at too high a level of abstraction.  I think. It won't let you see the values at specific memory addresses, which is what the OP needs to "confirm" the kind of thing he is interested in.  (Not that I think it is either an easy or worthwhile thing to do.  I mean, a physics student doesn't actually *need* to use a particle accelerator to validate what his text books tell him.)

Comment: Are you asking how to do that in a debugger? or are you asking how the program can _[reflect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming))_ on its own stacks? Last time I looked, a program could construct a `Throwable`, and then call its `getStackTrace()` method, but that only gives you the names of the function calls on the stack. It doesn't give you any information about the local variables.

Comment: in Java9, you can use StackFrame and StackWalker:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/42518450/1206301