# How to get the application call stack from OpenJDK code?

Tags: java, c++

I'm working on one OpenJDK project, where I need to get the call stack of running aplication (Jav program) inside OpenJDK source code.

Explanation:
For example:
When I run the following java program with my OpenJDK build

```
class Test{
   public static void main(String[] args){
      System.out.println("Testing Call Stack Program");
   }
}
```

Here when the control enters `println` statement, internally in the OpenJDK it hits 
`writeBytes()`.

Call Stack of JDK program is 
[image]

```
void
writeBytes(JNIEnv *env, jobject this, jbyteArray bytes,
           jint off, jint len, jboolean append, jfieldID fid)
{
    **//RETRIEVE THE CALL STACK OF APPLICATION and NOT THE CURRENT CALL STACK OF JDK** 
    jint n;
    char stackBuf[BUF_SIZE];
    char *buf = NULL;
    FD fd;

    if (IS_NULL(bytes)) {
        JNU_ThrowNullPointerException(env, NULL);
        return;
    }

    if (outOfBounds(env, off, len, bytes)) {
        JNU_ThrowByName(env, "java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException", NULL);
        return;
    }

    if (len == 0) {
        return;
    } else if (len > BUF_SIZE) {
        buf = malloc(len);
        if (buf == NULL) {
            JNU_ThrowOutOfMemoryError(env, NULL);
            return;
        }
    } else {
        buf = stackBuf;
    }

    (*env)->GetByteArrayRegion(env, bytes, off, len, (jbyte *)buf);

    if (!(*env)->ExceptionOccurred(env)) {
        off = 0;
        while (len > 0) {
            fd = GET_FD(this, fid);
            if (fd == -1) {
                JNU_ThrowIOException(env, "Stream Closed");
                break;
            }
            if (append == JNI_TRUE) {
                n = IO_Append(fd, buf+off, len);
            } else {
                n = IO_Write(fd, buf+off, len);
            }
            if (n == -1) {
                JNU_ThrowIOExceptionWithLastError(env, "Write error");
                break;
            }
            off += n;
            len -= n;
        }
    }
    if (buf != stackBuf) {
        free(buf);
    }
}
```

Here I need to get the application level call stack (that is I need to get the call stack of `System.out.println()` which is `main()` and then `println()`). How can we get the call stack from within the OpenJDK source?. Is that even possible to get the user level call stack from JDK source?.

Comment: How is this relevant to [c++]?

Comment: `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()`

Comment: You might consider reading the following question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069066/get-current-stack-trace-in-java

Comment: @RichardCritten Because OpenJDK is written in C/C++ and I need to get the call stack of Java program from OpenJDK (that's C++ code).

Comment: @Michael, it is to get the call stack in the java program itself. But I want call stack from OpenJDK (that is when writeByte() gets hit)