How to get a variable name in the caller class?
I wrote an extended JTextField class (MyClass) because JFormattedTextField didn't meet all my needs. Basically the class handles various format types, specified by a passed parameter.
 In a testing phase, all kinds of input strings are tested. In case such an input string is mistakenly rejected by my program, I would like to detect, in what instance/variable of MyClass this happened. This name together with the tested input string will then appear in a message, which the tester could forward to me for further inspection.
 I have found examples how to access a caller class and how to access variable names via reflection. But in order to use Class.getDeclaredField(String name) you have to know the name of the variable beforehand.
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class MyApp {
  static MyClass myGloballyDeclaredClass;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
//    MyClass myClassWithFormatType1= new MyClass(1);
//    MyClass myClassWithFormatType2= new MyClass(2);
//    MyClass myClassWithFormatTypeX= new MyClass(x);
    myGloballyDeclaredClass= new MyClass(10);
  }
}


class MyClass {
  public MyClass(int flag) {
    boolean unexpectedInput= true;
    if (unexpectedInput) {
      Class<?> clazz= StackWalker
            .getInstance(StackWalker.Option.RETAIN_CLASS_REFERENCE)
            .getCallerClass();

//      Field f= clazz.getDeclaredField(String name);
//           The name is exactly what I want to detect.
//      Retrieving all fields is of no use, as there are many
//      instances of MyClass and I'm looking for an unknown
//      specific one.
//      Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
//      String variableName= ...; // This is the missing code.
      System.out.println("This instance of MyClass was called in "+
                         clazz.getName()+"\n"+
                         "and stored in variable ..."); // +variableName
    }
  }
}

I could, of course, pass the instance name as a string parameter to MyClass, but if the name could be elicited with code, it would not only be nicer, but also a help in future unforeseen requirements.
Edit
Matt and Old Dog Programmer pointed to an examination of the stack trace, which worked nice in the beginning. But when it comes closer to my Swing app, the creation line of MyTextField in MySwingApp is no more listed in the stack.
Here's the skeleton
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MySwingApp extends JFrame {
  MyTextField myTextField;

  public MySwingApp() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(300, 240);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

//    MyTextField myTextFieldWithFlag1= new MyTextField(1);
//    MyTextField myTextFieldWithFlag2= new MyTextField(2);
//    MyTextField myTextFieldWithFlagX= new MyTextField(x);
    myTextField= new MyTextField(10);
    add(myTextField, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(new JLabel("""
    <html>Enter any character string.<br>
    Letter "e" will be treated as erroneous and<br>
    launch a stack display.</html>"""));
    setVisible(true);
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(MySwingApp::new);
  }

}

============================================

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class MyTextField extends JTextField {
  AbstractDocument doc = (AbstractDocument)this.getDocument();
  TheFilter filter;

  public MyTextField(int flag) {
    filter= new TheFilter(this);
    doc.setDocumentFilter(filter);
  }


  public void showStackTrace() {
    String stackTrace = "Stack Trace:\n";
//    StackTraceElement[] elements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
    StackTraceElement[] elements = new Throwable().getStackTrace();
    for(StackTraceElement ste : elements) {
      stackTrace+= ste.toString() + "\n";
    }
    System.out.println(stackTrace);
  }


  class TheFilter extends DocumentFilter {
    public TheFilter(MyTextField docOwner) {
    }

    public void insertString(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset,
        String str, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
    }

    public void remove(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length)
                        throws BadLocationException {
    }

    public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length,
        String str, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
//    Letter "e" is deemed to be an erroneous input.
      if (str.equals("e")) {
        showStackTrace();
        return;
      }
      else
        fb.replace(offset, length, str, attrs);
    }
  }

}


When an error occurs, you will pass the instance to the logger and if necessary, acquire that attribute when you make the logging call won't you?

You asked this before, the answer was 'java does not work this way, but, you can use a hashmap'. The answer hasn't changed.

If MyClass is your class, you simply add a getFormatType() method and call it from wherever you're logging the error. If you're handling it as JTextField, you can still check instanceof MyClass, if it's the case you cast and call the method, else you log something like "not MyClass". If none of these responds to your requirement, you will need to show more code (specifically where you're catching the exception and try to log the format type)

@rzwitserloot Yes, it's the same question. A moderator asked me to clarify/repost it. I haven't seen any 'hashmap' comment though. - It's not so much about catching or logging errors/exceptions. It's that the testing team could find input that the programme currently erroneously rejects. If I receive the variable name in the tester's notification, he is spared a detailed description where the error occured.

Doesn't the stack trace tell you where the error occurred?

@matt Well, I never worked with StackWalker so far and look at the stack trace only when an exception is thrown (which is not the case in my code). In the stack trace I find class names, method names and line numbers, but no variable names - or do I miss something?

Hmm, I thought a failed test gives a stack trace. So then you can go to the line in the source code and see the variable name.

You can get the stack trace without creating or throwing an exception.  You can get the stack trace as a StackTraceElement[] by calling Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace(). See the checked answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069066/how-can-i-get-the-current-stack-trace-in-java

@all -Thanks for your input. - A simplistic example: I have created an instance of MyClass which accepts numeric input only. Now the tester enters "123A56" and receives an error message. The tester does not agree, as under certain conditions the 4th character can indeed be A. So he copies his input and the error message and transmits both to be. If the error message contains the instance/variable name of MyClass, I can immediately check with what flags this instance was created. Then either I have to modify the code of this flag or create code for an additonal new flag.

@Old Dog Programmer - I just tested with both Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace() and new Throwable().getStackTrace(). Class names I can find, but no instance names.

Combine that with the suggestion from @matt: If you really, really need to get the name of the variable programmatically , It's round-about and not efficient, but you could conceivably open the source file, read it to the line of code referenced in the stack trace, and parse that line to get the name of the variable. But, I would think having the source code file name and line number would be enough.

@Old Dog Programmer - You are right: The line number of the caller where MyClass is created will be enough. - The suggested approach works if there is one caller only - and I was quite happy seeing this in my simplified test case. However, MyClass has an inner class (an extended DocumentListener) where the actual filtering takes place. It seems that the stack trace shows only the immediate caller, whereas I would now need the caller of the caller - and I am not very confident that this is possible.

Isn't the caller of the caller another element in the stack trace? Can you update your code to show an example with the inner class?

@Old Dog Programmer  I had to make a skeleton of my application to produce a stack trace which didn't show the creation line of MyTextField in MySwingApp any more.

What if the information about the instance was captured at the time it was created?
package instanceid;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class MyTextField extends JTextField {

    AbstractDocument doc = (AbstractDocument) this.getDocument();
    TheFilter filter;
    private final String id;
    private static int serialNumber;

    public MyTextField(int flag) {

        filter = new TheFilter(this);
        doc.setDocumentFilter(filter);
        id = generateID(flag);
    }

    private static String generateID(int flag) {
        StackTraceElement[] theTrace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
        return "instance " + serialNumber++ + " of MyClass created from "
                + theTrace[3].getClassName() + " in "
                + theTrace[3].getFileName() + " @ "
                + theTrace[3].getLineNumber()
                + " with value " + flag;
    }

Followed by the rest of the O/P's code.
When System.out.println(id); is called in an instance method, such as replace , the output looks like this:
instance 0 of MyClass created from instanceid.MySwingApp in MySwingApp.java @ 20 with value 10
Of course, a public String getID () { return id; } could be added.
Note: If this information is to be programmatically captured from the stack, it has to be done early. The stack has entries only for  active methods. So, when the constructor or any other method returns to the caller, that information is removed from the stack.
